# Does "stringstream" copy the string on which it is constructed?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

In a piece of code like this one

```
std::string s("random;string;");
std::stringstream s_stream(s);
```

does `s_stream` make a copy of `s`?

I mean, what would happen if, after creating `s_stream`, I modified `s`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream - "Uses a copy of str as initial contents of the underlying string device."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream

> 2) Uses a copy of `str` as initial contents of the underlying string device. The underlying `basic_stringbuf` object is constructed as `basic_stringbuf<Char,Traits,Allocator>(str, mode)`.

Comment: Is there an alternative that doesn't do that?

Comment: @ingomueller.net, I don't see any. It would have been nice to have a constructor that accepted a rvalue reference, and could use `std::string`'s move constructor to avoid the copy.